# railstutorial.org 4.4.5 A user class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I'm getting an error with chapter 4.4.5 A user class.
When in rails console, it says to type

> require './example_user'

which returns the correct result **true**.

The next line says to type

> example = User.new

which returns the following:

> 2.3.0 :002 > example = User.new
>   NameError: uninitialized constant User

Not sure how to get past this point, as I am following this step by step.

Comment: Your User class isn't loaded.  What are the contents of the /example_user file?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to `require` any of your models from the rails console as long as your models are defined in `app/models`. Make sure your user is defined in `app/models/user.rb` with the following syntax:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

And that you're running your `rails c` command within the root of your app directory.